# Expandable Thumbnail grid Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I was using a plugin of sorts located here to pull this off. I have been working on this page for a few hours wen I checked with my client. He stated that he does not want me to use a plugin. He referenced the jQuery Animate but I am such a noob to writing my own code I am not sure where to start with all that. I included an image of what I need it to do and look like but I need some help finding a solution. Thank you for all your help and time!)

I need to add that the description will always expand directly under the leaders thumbnail. I would like it to be seemless for mobile users as well. If possible?

[image]

```
<div class="container leaderShipwrapper gallery-items">
    <ul id="items" class="row list-unstyled">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-1 leaderShipgrid">
            <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="joe" data-title="developer" data-profile="profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="ray" data-title="dunce" data-profile="dunce profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="joe" data-title="developer" data-profile="profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="joe" data-title="developer" data-profile="profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="joe" data-title="developer" data-profile="profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <li id="1" class="leaderDescription"><div class="leaderName">NAME</div><div class="leaderTitle">TITLE</div><div class="leaderProfile">Description for row 1 cell 1</div></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
          $(this).find('.hover-dropdown').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(150);
        }, function() {
          $(this).find('.hover-dropdown').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(105)
        });

        $('.leader').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.leaderDescription').find('.leaderName').text($(this).attr('data-name'));
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.leaderDescription').find('.leaderTitle').text($(this).attr('data-title'));
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.leaderDescription').find('.leaderProfile').text($(this).attr('data-profile'));
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.leaderDescription').slideDown();
    });

    });
```

Ok, so I have at a good point to ask this question now. I need to know what I need to do to get this closer to the image above. I have the first row and I am getting the data to load correctly I just cant get the slide up if one is already open then slide down the new one that was clicked. I also need it to open the info below the leaders photo like the in the photo I added. Please let me know how far I am from this?

Comment: Can anyone point me in the right direction for this module?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly what you want is a div with an id tag which is toggled using jquery on some sort of event, maybe when someone clicks one of the images. For the first part you need something like this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slideToggle demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    width: 400px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Toggle</button>
<p>
  This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
  should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
  your life.  Congratulations!
</p>

<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is from http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ ,

You will also want to load dynamically information from a server perhaps. You can use jQuery for this to with this function: http://api.jquery.com/load/
Example from the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Projects:</b>
<ol id="new-projects"></ol>

<script>
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/load.html #projects li" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But where is the information about the users stored? Some server you are suppose to write? The AJAX part of the code will allow you to click one of the users and then load the code dynamically for them.

You will need to tell each picture to react on click. This can be done with the .each() function of jQuery, where you iterate each li element (the pictures).

Comment: So all of my code will be added to our sitecore installation. I was hoping to get a simple div to be toggles I guess that would sit inside the main wrapper of each row item. eg this seems to do exactly what I want but I need to do it without a plugin.

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

Comment: I also need to make sure when one is open and another is clicked the open one needs to close. 


54N1 - Would this kind of method be best?
`<li>
      <a href="#" data-largesrc="images/2.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
       <img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
      </a>
     </li>`